# How to store to a db and append the results in a new div after an event with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, symfony

I am managing social group wall and trying to find a solution for making my group wall dynamic without refreshing the page. There is a text area and want when click post button. Data is stored in database and on refreshing the page I want to find the text that i have already post it:

Here is the script:

```
  <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#btnpost").click(function () {
                    $("#publication").prepend('<div class="panel panel-success rounded shadow" style="text-align: left;margin-bottom: 5px;">' +
                                    '<div class="panel-heading no-border">'+
                                    '<div class="pull-left half">'+
                                    '<div class="media" style="text-align: left;">'+
                                    '<div class="media-object pull-left" style="margin-top: 35px;">'+
                            '<img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar2.png" style="width: 40px;height: 40px;">' +
                            '</div>'+
                            '</div>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                            '<a href="">test profile</a>'+
                            '<span class="text-white h6" style="display: block; color: black;">on 8th June, 2014</span>'+
                            '<br>'+
                            '<span style="color: black;margin-bottom: 10px;word-break: break-all  ">#wonderful place man congratulationhh </span>'+
                            '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="panel-footer">'+
                    '<form action="#" class="form-horizontal">'+
                            '<div class="form-group has-feedback no-margin">'+
                            '<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Votre commentaire ici..." style="width: 95%;margin-left: 10px;">'+
                            '</div>'+
                            '</form>'+
                            '</div>');
                });
            });
        </script>
```

i want to find how can i make the data stored in their divs

Comment: Use AJAX to send the data to the server.

Comment: after storing data i want to now how to update the view because after refreshing everything is gone

Comment: You put the information in a database. When you reload the page, it gets the information from the database to recreate the page.

Comment: okey thnks i will try this

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing all your code here is an example

`user_id, title, posttext` are just the text fields that users input into. The `user_id` is so you can identify the user when sending to your database.

You send those values as a `POST` to your script which in this example is `post.php` but you can use whatever.

After the `POST` comes back ajax will send the result back in `data`, but that will be depended on how you are returning it and what your needs are. You can either send it back with a delimiter and use `split()` to explode it or you can send it back as `json`.

This method will not refresh the page and will generate the data right on your page.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnpost").click(function () {
        // get user data input
        var user_id = $('#user_id').val();
        var title = $('#title').val();
        var posttext = $('#posttext').val();

        // send data to db with post
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "post.php?",
            data:"user_id="+ user_id+
            "&title="+ title+
            "&posttext="+ posttext
            success: function (data) {
                // on successful return data and prepend
                $("#publication").prepend(
                    '<div class="panel panel-success rounded shadow" style="text-align: left;margin-bottom: 5px;">' +
                    '<div class="panel-heading no-border">'+
                    '<div class="pull-left half">'+
                    '<div class="media" style="text-align: left;">'+
                    '<div class="media-object pull-left" style="margin-top: 35px;">'+
                    '<img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar2.png" style="width: 40px;height: 40px;">' +
                    '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<a href="">test profile</a>'+
                    '<span class="text-white h6" style="display: block; color: black;">on 8th June, 2014</span>'+
                    '<br>'+
                    '<span style="color: black;margin-bottom: 10px;word-break: break-all  ">#wonderful place man congratulationhh </span>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="panel-footer">'+
                    '<form action="#" class="form-horizontal">'+
                    '<div class="form-group has-feedback no-margin">'+
                    '<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Votre commentaire ici..." style="width: 95%;margin-left: 10px;">'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '</form>'+
                    '</div>'
                );
            }
        });     
    });
});
</script>
```